# Арифметические операции на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Учу JS, есть такой код:

```
var str = '*';
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    document.write(str+'<br/>');
    str+='*';
}
```

Что значит `+=`, как понять это действие? То есть `строка = строка + значение строки`?
Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вы все правильно поняли.

Часто нужно применить оператор к переменной и сохранить результат в ней же, например:

```
var n = 2;
n = n + 5;
n = n * 2;
```

Эту запись можно укоротить при помощи совмещённых операторов, вот так:

```
var n = 2;
n += 5; // теперь n=7 (работает как n = n + 5)
n *= 2; // теперь n=14 (работает как n = n * 2)

alert( n ); // 14
```

Так можно сделать для операторов +,-,*,/,% и бинарных <<,>>,>>>,&,|,^.

Вызов с присваиванием имеет в точности такой же приоритет, как обычное присваивание, то есть выполнится после большинства других операций:

```
var n = 2;
n *= 3 + 5;
```

> https://learn.javascript.ru/operators